# Getting data using TensorFlow and apply Cross Validation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cross-validation, tf.keras

Im using tensorflow/keras to get my data (images) from a folder containing 2 different classes ('0' and '1') as it follows:

[image]

And the code responsable for this:

```
train_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        base_folder,
        label_mode='categorical', #multiclass
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size = batch_size, #16
        subset='training',
        validation_split = 0.2,
        seed=123
    )
    
validation_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        base_folder,
        label_mode='categorical', #multiclass
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size = batch_size, #16
        subset='validation',
        validation_split = 0.2,
        seed=123
    )
```

After that Im using those datasets to train my model (CNN).
So, knowing that the return of the function " ***tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory***" its an array with a lot of mini-batches, my problem is: how can I use Cross Validation with this specific train_dataset and validation_dataset variables ?

Comment: Why do you want to apply cross validation here? Did you tried to validate with cross validation?